# Improve 'case'-'when' performance

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have a `case` construction with ~50 conditions, each of whose cases has a different logic and cannot be merged together or re-used. The construction gets larger every time I add a new case. Currently it takes ~150 lines of code.

```
case variable
when 'condition 1'
    some complicated logic for condition 1
when 'condition 2'
    some complicated logic for condition 2
...
when 'condition 50'
    some complicated logic for condition 50
end
```

Is there anyway to refactor this code? I'm thinking of two ways:

- I create a constant array to store all conditions and create a loop to check `variable`. (But I cannot apply the logic to each case.)
- I put each condition's logic into different methods. (But it's still messy and is spread over many lines.)

  ```
  case variable
  when 'condition 1'
    condition_1(arg)
  when 'condition 2'
    condition_2(arg)
  ...
  when 'condition 50'
    condition_50(arg)
  end

  def condition_1(arg)
    some complicated logic for condition 1
  end

  def condition_2(arg)
    some complicated logic for condition 2
  end

  ...

  def condition_50(arg)
    some complicated logic for condition 50
  end
  ```

Which way is better?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Comment: thanks, interesting, I don't know about these Refactoring methods

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to move the logic to a module and define each case's method there, then you can just include the module in the class which needs those methods inside the case switch.

```
module MyModule
  def case_1(data)
    #process your data logic here
  end
  def case_2(data)
    #process your data logic here
  end
end
```

then inside your Class just do

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule

  def some_method(arg)
    case variable
    when 'condition 1'
    case_1(arg)
    when 'condition 2'
    case_2(arg)
  end


end
```

However if the name of the method which will be called can be derived from a consistent pattern such as `condition 1` or `condition 2`  Then you don't need the case at all and can do meta-programming where the method name can be called based on the argument.  You can use the `define_method` to do this. See https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method which you could still do in the module to keep the logic there.  But call the method using a lambda

so inside your class

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule

  def some_method(arg)
    method_name = lambda  {|arg| meth = "case_#{arg}".to_sym}
    method_name.call(arg)
  end

end
```

Comment: I see, it'll be a little tricky to use meta programming in my situation, but I'll try. Thanks